# Schnell Flame Suspension Configuration

Tags: suspension

Do anyone have any idea about Schnell Flame Suspension Configuration like bounce absorption, jump capabilities, pot holes*disk brake measures etc.

Comment: Hi again Rupa. The next thing to do is edit your question so that it asks for specific information or advice that is not available by a quick Google. Is [this](http://schnellbikes.com/products/bike/duel-suspension/flames) the bike you're asking about? If so, it looks very BSO to me, and whatever it's specs I would question it's durability. Good luck with that :-)

Comment: The design is called unified rear triangle or URT, and Google will find some colorful opinions about it.